# Call to a member function addOrderFilter() on null in [...]app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\paketid\shipping.phtml on line 3

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I want to read all the records from one table, but I got Fatal Error in my phtml file.

My `paketid_booking_result` table structure and it already has some records:

`entity_id | order_id | booking_id | created_by_user_id | from_full | from_email | from_name | from_phone | from_address | from_zipcode | from_country_code | to_full | to_name | to_name | to_phone | to_address | to_zipcode | to_country_code | booking_code | booking_date | expiry_date`

I tried to select only `booking_code` (for test) where `$order` in `shipping.phtml` :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('PaketId_Shipping');?>
<?php $order = $this->getOrder()?>
<?php $shipping = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getConnection()->addOrderFilter($order) ?>
<?php if(count($shipping)):
foreach($shipping as $shipping): ?>
<h1>Test custom block</h1>
<h2><?php echo $shipping->getBookingCode() ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My block :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Shipment_View_Shipping extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
protected $order;

public function getOrder() {
    if (is_null($this->order)) {
        if (Mage::registry('current_order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('order');
        }
        else {
            $order = new Varien_Object();
        }
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    return $this->order;
}
```

}

My `config.xml` :

```
<config>
<modules>
<PaketId_Shipping>
  <version>1.0</version>
</PaketId_Shipping>
</modules>
<global>

<blocks>
  <paketid_shipping>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Block</class>
  </paketid_shipping>
</blocks>
<resources>
<shipping_write>
  <connection>
    <use>core_write</use>
  </connection>
</shipping_write>
<shipping_read>
  <connection>
    <use>core_read</use>
  </connection>
</shipping_read>
</resources>

<models>

  <paketid_shipping>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>paketid_shipping_result</resourceModel>
  </paketid_shipping>

  <paketid_shipping_resource>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
  </paketid_shipping_resource>

  <paketid_shipping_resource>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
      <entities>
        <result>
          <table>paketid_shipping_result</table>
        </result>
      </entities>
  </paketid_shipping_resource>

</models>
<helpers>
  <paketid_shipping>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Helper</class>
  </paketid_shipping>
</helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <paketid_shipping>
      <file>paketid_shipping.xml</file>
    </paketid_shipping>
  </updates>
</layout>
</adminhtml>
<default>
<carriers>
  <paketid_shipping>
    <active>1</active>
    <sallowspecific>1</sallowspecific>
<model>paketid_shipping/carrier</model>
    <name>Paket ID Shipping Extension</name>
    <price>10.00</price>
<title>Paket ID Shipping Extension</title>
  </paketid_shipping>
</carriers>
</default>
</config>
```

My model `[...]app/code/community/PaketId/Shipping/Model/Resource/Result.php` :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result extends Mage_EAV_Model_Entity_Abstract {
public function __construct()
{
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $this->setType('paketid_shipping_result');
    $this->setConnection(
        $resource->getConnection('shipping_read'),
        $resource->getConnection('shipping_write')
    );
}}
```

My model `[...]app/code/community/PaketId/Shipping/Model/Resource/Result/Collection.php` :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result');
}

public function addOrderFilter($order)
{
    if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $order = (int) $order->getId();
    }
    if (!is_array($order)) {
        $order = array($order);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.order_id IN (?)", $order);

    return $this;
}
protected function _toOptionArray($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='booking_code', $additional=array())
{
    return parent::_toOptionArray($valueField, $labelField, $additional);
}
protected function _toOptionHash($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='booking_code')
{
    return parent::_toOptionHash($valueField, $labelField);
}
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    return $countSelect;
}
}
```

Comment: where should i add it?

Answer (score 0):

In `shipping.phtml`

File do below changes

```
<?php $order = $block->getOrder()?> 
<?php $shipping = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getConnection()->‌​ddOrderFilter($orde‌​r) ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'example for block file' part and I replaced my previous code in `collection.php` as you suggest me but i still got the same fatal error :(

Comment: yes, i changed my previous `$this->getSelect()` function to the one you suggested

Comment: yes, the same error :(

Comment: `echo $shipping->getBookingCode()` doesn't echo anything, also it gives me no error. I changed `$this` into `$block` like u said

Comment: Your `Call to a member function addOrderFilter() on null` error is solved right?

Comment: yes, the error is gone now, but my query doesn't return anything. my `echo $shipping->getBookingCode()` still not working

Comment: also, where is the `$block` coming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45447/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-may).